# undefined method `complete_name' but the method is already defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My Controller:

```
class RoomsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_room, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def nome_completo
    "#{title}, #{location}"
  end


  # GET /rooms
  # GET /rooms.json
  def index
    @rooms = Room.all
  end

  # GET /rooms/1
  # GET /rooms/1.json
  def show
  end


  # GET /rooms/new
  def new
    @room = Room.new
  end

  # GET /rooms/1/edit
  def edit
  end
......
end
```

My View:

```
<h1>Quartos recém postados</h1>
<ul>
    <% @rooms.each do |room| %>
    <li><%= link_to room.nome_completo , room %></li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

> The error:
>       undefined method `nome_completo' for #Room:0x0000000ed6d478

As you can see I have already defined my method in the controller, but when I try to call it in the view I got this message. This is happening with all methods that I define but not with the methods that came with the class.

P.S Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Your method is defined on the `RoomsController` when it should be instead defined inside the `Room` model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method is missing in the `Room` model, not the controller. You error states the exact same.

> The error: undefined method `nome_completo' for #Room:0x0000000ed6d478

If the method was being called on the `RoomsController` you'd see:

> The error: undefined method `nome_completo' for #RoomsController:0x0000000ed6d478

The controller is responsible for requests and responses, the `Room` model is responsible for rooms.

Add your method to `app/models/room.rb`.

```
class Room < ActiveRecord::Base # ApplicationRecord Rails >= 5
  def nome_completo
    "#{title}, #{location}"
  end
end
```